# SQL Server Integer Formatting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure that queries some data and emails it, I'd like to change the procedure so that any numbers in the thousands get displayed with commas like 1,000. I guess the best way of doing this in SQL is to convert it to a string and add the comma?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a *relatively* clean answer.  Convert to money (no data type loss).  Then convert to varchar with style 1 (it does the commas for you) and then remove the .00 from the end, since it comes with the money data type.

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(MONEY, 1234), 1), '.00', '')
```

It's a fine line to figure out how many string manipulations before doing an inline function, but this should be a pretty quick conversion.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 1):

Correct. An integer has no formatting by definition of the data type.

So you must either convert the value to a string(varchar for example) or as is the more common practice, have the presentation tier handle the formatting of the value.

Comment: In this case there is no presentation tied as the stored procedure if firing an email with the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck using SQL Server as the presentation of the email (no other report application),

`SELECT CONVERT(varchar(24),CONVERT(money,CAST( 12345678 AS VarChar(24))),1)`

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without the decimal places?